# Is there a way to stage data using Maven and Junit 5?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

We are using Maven to run JUnit5 functional tests.  Most of the tests require data to go through our entire system (a Storm topology) which could take around 1 minute.  We need to send some data through and then wait 1 minute before we run the tests.

We need to stage the data and then communicate keys and such to the tests.

**Is there a way to run a method/class to stage the data, then wait one minute, then run the rest of the tests?**

Comment: It sounds like you're running integration tests, and this activity is a good candidate for the `pre-integration-test` phase.

Comment: Any other info on this?  A link maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Until there is first-class support for *suites* in JUnit 5, one alternative is to create an extension that implements `BeforeAllCallback`, is registered globally via the `ServiceLoader` mechanism, and makes use of `CloseableResource` and the `ExtentionContext.Store` to achieve suite-like behavior.

See [issue #1555](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1555) and the discussion on Gitter linked from there for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JUNIT supports before/after test-suite abilities yet; I see numerous people asking for it though: e.g. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/456.

On a per test class basis, you can use @BeforeClass to initialize the data for the tests in that class though.  So, this would let you do that staging once per class rather than once per test which could be a pretty good win if your classes have many tests each (assuming I understand what you're asking here!).

Comment: Yes, I have BeforeClass coded up but I have hundreds of tests to run.  Even paralleling them is not going to be fast enough.  I need BeforeRun or BeforeTests.